# How to paginate react-admin lists when the total is unknown?

Tags: aws-appsync, react-admin

**Summary**: I can't get a total number of records from my GraphQL endpoint.  I only know if I have reached the end of my GraphQL records list when I am parsing the response from the endpoint. How can I make my custom pagination component aware that it's on the last page?

**Details**: I'm using React Admin with AWS AppSync (GraphQL on DynamoDB) using `ra-data-graphql`. AppSync can't tell you the total number of records available to a list query, and it also limits the number of records you can return to a 1MB payload. Instead, it includes a `nextToken` value if there are more records to query, which you can include in subsequent list queries.

I have created a custom pagination component that only uses "prev" and "next" links, which is fine. But I need to know when the last page is displayed. Right now, I only know this in the `parseResponse()` function that I'm passing in to `buildQuery()` for the list query. At this point, I have access to the `nextToken` value. If it's empty, then I have fetched the last page of results from AppSync. If I could pass this value, or even a boolean e.g. `lastPage` to the custom pagination component, I'd be all set. How can I do this in React Admin?

Comment: Looking at [the docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customreducers), using `customReducers` might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a way to adapt AppSync resolver to work with `page` and `perPage` native react-admin parameters.

It's a bad practice because query response is limited by 1MB and also full dynamodb query response needs to be parsed and transformed for each page query, however it does the trick.

## VTL AppSync resolver Request Mapping Template:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        "expression": "userId = :userId",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":userId" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.identity.sub)
        }
    }
}
```

## VTL AppSync resolver Response Mapping Template:

```
#set($result = {})
#set($result.items = [])
#set($result.length = $ctx.result.items.size())
#set($start = $ctx.arguments.perPage * ($ctx.arguments.page - 1))
#set($end = $ctx.arguments.perPage * $ctx.arguments.page - 1)
#if($end > $result.length - 1)
 #set($end = $result.length - 1)
#end

#if($start <= $result.length - 1 && $start >= 0 )
  #set($range = [$start..$end])
  #foreach($i in $range)
     $util.qr($result.items.add($ctx.result.items[$i]))
  #end
#end 

$util.toJson($result)
```

## dataProvider.js

```
...
const buildQuery = () => (
  raFetchType,
  resourceName,
  params
) => {
  if (resourceName === "getUserToDos" && raFetchType === "GET_LIST") {
    return {
      query: gql`
        query getUserToDos($perPage: Int!, $page: Int!) {
          getUserToDos(perPage: $perPage, page: $page) {
            length
            items {
              todoId
              date
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      variables: {
        page: params.pagination.page,
        perPage: params.pagination.perPage
      },
      parseResponse: ({ data }) => {
        return {
          data: data.getUserToDos.items.map(item => {
            return { id: item.listingId, ...item };
          }),
          total: data.getUserToDos.length
        };
      }
    };
  }
...
```

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to this. The solution I posted was awkward and yielded unpredictable results when moving from create/edit back to list. That said, I opted to not paginate at all, as the number of records was not too great and the RA filters provide an adequate UX.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this I created a custom reducer, `nextTokenReducer` that looks for React Admin's `CRUD_GET_LIST_SUCCESS` action, the payload of which is the entire response from the AppSync GraphQL endpoint. I can pull the `nextToken` value out of that:

```
import { CRUD_GET_LIST_SUCCESS } from "react-admin";

export default (previousState = null, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === CRUD_GET_LIST_SUCCESS) {
    return payload.nextToken;
  }
  return previousState;
};
```

I passed this custom reducer to the `Admin` component in my main `App` component:

```
import nextTokenReducer from "./reducers/nextTokenReducer";
...
class App extends Component {
...
  render() {
    const { dataProvider } = this.state;

    if (!dataProvider) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }

    return (
      <Admin
        customReducers={{ nextToken: nextTokenReducer }}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
      >
        <Resource name="packs" list={PackList} />
      </Admin>
    );
  }
}
```

I then connected the `nextToken` store to my custom pagination component. It will display "next", "prev", or nothing based on whether `nextToken` is in its props:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRight from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

class CustomPagination extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.page === 1 && !this.props.nextToken) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        {this.props.page > 1 && (
          <Button
            color="primary"
            key="prev"
            icon={<ChevronLeft />}
            onClick={() => this.props.setPage(this.props.page - 1)}
          >
            Prev
          </Button>
        )}
        {this.props.nextToken && (
          <Button
            color="primary"
            key="next"
            icon={<ChevronRight />}
            onClick={() => this.props.setPage(this.props.page + 1)}
            labelposition="before"
          >
            Next
          </Button>
        )}
      </Toolbar>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nextToken: state.nextToken });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CustomPagination);
```

Finally, I passed the custom pagination component into my list component:

```
import React from "react";
import { List, Datagrid, DateField, TextField, EditButton } from "react-admin";
import CustomPagination from "./pagination";

export const PackList = props => (
  <List {...props} pagination={<CustomPagination />}>
    <Datagrid>
    ...
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

Comment: How can I increase the query limit on a resource?

Comment: @Berni, [you can't](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html).

"A single Query operation can retrieve a maximum of 1 MB of data. This limit applies before any FilterExpression is applied to the results. If LastEvaluatedKey is present in the response and is non-null, you will need to paginate the result set (see Paginating the Results)."

Comment: This is the best answer for appsync/dynamodb/amplify. messing with VTL, scanning, trying to do what dynamodb wasn't built to do, is smell, IMO. Cheers for the great solution.